# How do I set the padding-top based on height of a div in JQuery or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hey guys so I have a product site and each product's div's height is different based on the info entered.

I need a div I have that is `position: absolute` with a `padding-top:58em;` to have the `padding-top` automatically fill in based on the height of the one div that contains all the product info.  I am not to sure on how to do this so if you guys could help I would appreciate :)

Hope this makes sense, if not please let me know!

Comment: You say "based on the height of the one div that contains all the product info," but what is the algorithm for calculating what the padding should be based on said height?

Comment: What do you mean?  I do not have anything calculating any height I want to figure out how to do that.

Comment: What I'm asking is say you have that div with the products and its height is 500px.  If so, what should the padding-top of the other div be?  500px?  250px?  Something else?

Comment: oh ya the product div is a set height of 400px, sometimes that changes.  That's why I want to create a JQuery function or javascript to make a function that will get the height of that div and set the right amount of distance of padding-top.  I would like it in em to.

Comment: Okay that's a start, but how do you calculate the "right amount?"

Comment: That's why I am asking you, lol.  Check it out go to prodjsoundlighting.com click a product and you will see once you scroll down theres a bar that has about/specs and reviews.  Sometimes the content right under it gets caught up on top of that and so I need to have that level off with a padding-top in-between in the right spot, do you get what I am saying?\

Comment: Can you provide a specific link? I don't seem to be able to reproduce that behavior

Comment: http://www.prodjsoundlighting.com/2-cvi-252/

Answer (score 0):

Is your intention to calculate the padding-top to make sure all of your content is lined up at the bottom? For example, are you looking to do this: http://pastehtml.com/view/cq0m3bubz.html ?

If this is what you're looking for, rather than setting the padding-top programmatically you can just set the following attributes (assuming the container div has a fixed height already set):

```
#parent {
    display: table;
}

#child {
     display: table-cell;
     vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

I hope this is what you were looking for!

Comment: This should work in all browsers except very old versions of IE.

Comment: The one div that I want set with the padding-top is a absolute type, so will this work?

Comment: My above suggestion will work with absolute positioning; Try it and see if it solves your problem; if not, please try to clarify your original question so someone can give you a better answer.

Comment: Ya this does not work because the div that I am trying to have calculate the height of the other div and go from is outside of it so it does not have a parent.